# Do we need a visa for an overnight trip UK to Paris and back?

Tags: visas, schengen, eurostar, japanese-citizens

I'm travelling with my boyfriend this year to the UK and we want to take an overnight trip to Paris. He has a Japanese passport, I have a British one. We want to take the Eurostar together.

Does he need to prepare a visa for this trip? Any advice for us? I've been to Paris once from the UK but I'm not sure how it works for a non-EU passport.

Answer (score 9):

Japanese passport holders have visa free access to the Schengen Area and the UK, he will just have to go in a separate queue at immigration for non-EU passport holders and get a stamp in his passport.

[Do Japanese passport holders need a schengen visa?](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/)

[Do Japanese passport holders need a UK visa?](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/japan/tourism)

Comment: There are a few requirements like a machine-readable passport, passport validity, etc, but I expect them to be the same as for the UK.

Comment: You can join him in his passport queue, if you want.

Comment: When using the Eurostar, at St Pancras there are usually no separate queues for EU/EEA/CH citizens v the rest of the world. There are separate queues at Gare du Nord  on the way back though. Note that he will have to fill out a landing card in that direction.